# Mesibo on-premises integration issue using google cloud

Tags: mesibo

I'm trying to deploy Mesibo On-Premise with Google Cloud.

Mesibo Console shows following status: *"running but not accessible - refer to Firewall settings in the on-premise doc"*:

[image: Picture 1]

Logs by running Mesibo container:
[image: Picture 2]

Firewall settings for Mesibo on the Google Cloud have highest priority and allow all external IPs through all ports to connect to all instances:
[image: Picture 3]

The connection between SQL database and Mesibo On-Premise server was verified. Strict mode is disabled.

The problem was in the missing command ***--net=host*** by applying docker
$ sudo docker run -d mesibo/mesibo <APP_TOKEN>

Answer (score 0):

Is your IP address changed? I could not ping the IP address in the screenshot nor `netcat`. It is recommended to use a fixed IP address with mesibo. Once mesibo running on your server, click on the check status and the IP address will be refreshed. use `netcat` or similar tools to see if it is accessible from the public network

Comment: The IP address was static. I did some experiments in between. That's why it was changed. The new static IP is 34.89.145.208. It can be accessed via netcat from outside only through port 22 (ssh). netstat --listen confirms this information.  I still have the same issue and statement in mesibo console: "running but not accessible...".

Comment: You have answered your question. As you have said server is only accessible through port 22. That means your firewall is not open.

Comment: As I mentioned in the main topic all ports for all IPs are open with applied firewall rules. The question is why mesibo instance is not listening on dedicated ports mentioned in mesibo documentation 5222 and 5228?

Comment: I missed the --net=host parameter by sudo doker run... Now it works. Thanks!